# Determine Fortran derived type size in memory

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran, derived-types

The Fortran intrinsic function `transfer` can be used to covert a derived type into a real or integer array. This is potentially very useful when working in legacy systems which relies on arrays of primitive types (integer, real etc.) for persistence.

The code below runs at least on `ifort` and `gfortran` and converts a simple derived type example to an integer array (**updated with solution**):

```
program main
    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: int_mem_size = storage_size(1)

    type subtype
       integer a
       double precision b
    end type subtype

    type :: mytype
         integer :: foo
         double precision :: bar
         type(subtype) :: some_type
    end type

    type(mytype)  :: my_var
    type(subtype) :: my_subtype

    ! Old version: integer :: x(30)
    integer, allocatable :: x(:)
    integer :: mem_size

    !Allocate array with required size
    mem_size = storage_size(my_var)
    allocate(x(mem_size/int_mem_size))

    my_subtype%a = 1
    my_subtype%b = 2.7

    my_var%foo = 42
    my_var%bar = 3.14
    my_var%some_type = my_subtype

    write(*,*) "transfering..."
    x = transfer(my_var, x)
    write(*,*) "Integer transformation:", x

end program main
```

On my PC, this is the output (this result is at least platform dependent):

```
 transfering...
 Integer transformation:                    42           0  1610612736  1074339512         
 999           0    -1610612736  1074108825
```

My problem is that I have "guessed" that a 30 element long integer array is large enough to store this data structure. Is there a way I can determine how large the array needs to be to store the whole data structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a Fortran 2008 compliant compiler, or one that is compliant enough, you will find the intrinsic function `storage_size` which returns the number of bits used to store its argument.  Failing that most compilers that I am familiar with implement a non-standard function to do this; the Intel Fortran compiler has a function called `sizeof` which returns the number of bytes required to store its argument.

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thanks! I've updated the example code to reflect this solution for anyone interested